# springboot: writing array of object to db

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-boot, serialization

## Interested in single table

Below is the `JSON` file that I want to store in DB. How should I write the model class? Tried one sample model but it stores only the size of the object, not actual data. I can't retrieve the data also.

```
{
 sourceImageRepo: "xxx",
 sourceTagMatch: "xxx",
 targetProject: "xxx",
 targetFiles: [
  {
      name: "xxx",
      pattern: "xxx"
  },
  {
      name: "xxx",
      pattern: "xxx"
  }
 ]
}
```

I've got an error message like this:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-12-10T06:36:42.745+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$PersistentEntityResourceSerializer$1[\"content\"]->com.example.demo.model.suiteInformations[\"targetFiles\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])",
    "path": "/suiteInformationses/1"
}
```

Current model

**suiteInformations.java**

```java
package com.example.demo.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@Entity
@Table(name = "suitesInformations")
public class suiteInformations {
    public suiteInformations(int id, String sourceImageRepo, String sourceTagMatch, String email, 
       String targetProject, ArrayList<TargetFiles> targetFiles) {
        this.id = id;
        this.sourceImageRepo = sourceImageRepo;
        this.sourceTagMatch = sourceTagMatch;
        Email = email;
        this.targetProject = targetProject;
        this.targetFiles = targetFiles;
    }

    public suiteInformations() {}

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    public int id;
    @Column(name = "sourceImageRepo")
    public String sourceImageRepo;
    @Column(name = "sourceTagMatch")
    public String sourceTagMatch;
    @Column(name = "Email")
    public String Email;
    @Column(name = "targetProject")
    public String targetProject;
    @Embedded
    public ArrayList<TargetFiles>  targetFiles;

    // getters/setters omitted

}
```

**TargetFiles.java**

```java
package com.example.demo.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@Embeddable
public class TargetFiles {
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String name;

    @Column(name = "pattern")
    public String pattern;
}
```

*DB content*

```
SELECT * FROM SUITESINFORMATIONS;
ID EMAIL  SOURCEIMAGEREPO SOURCETAGMATCH    SIZE     TARGETPROJECT
1   xxx    xxx               xxx            1          xxx
```

Comment: which database are you using? Also, specify the table DDL like the column datatype.

Comment: i am using internal h2 db for testing the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [spring-boot-starter-data-jpa](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa) dependency from Spring.  It may also benefit you to look at the [@Repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) annotation from Spring.

Example tutorial for `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Your `JSON` file could become a POJO class:

```
@Entity
public class SuiteInfo {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;

   private String sourceImageRepo;
   private String sourceTagMatch;
   private String targetProject;
   private List<SuiteFile> targetFiles;

   //relevant getters, setters, equals, etc

   public class SuiteFile {
      private String name;
      private String pattern;

      //relevant getters, setters, equals, etc
   }
}
```

A repository interface can then be created:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface SuiteInfoRepository extends CrudRepository<SuiteInfo, Long> {

  SuiteInfo findById(long id);

  // define other queries here
}
```

NOTE: (from: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)
`You need not write an implementation of the repository interface. Spring Data JPA creates an implementation when you run the application.`

Comment: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: suite_info, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(target_files)]

Comment: @PoojithKumarHegde, `java.util.List` was a mistaken import, it has been removed

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes for keys in json. I hope this is just a typo.

```
{
 "sourceImageRepo": "xxx",
 "sourceTagMatch": "xxx",
 "targetProject": "xxx",
 "targetFiles": [
  {
      "name": "xxx",
      "pattern": "xxx"
  },
  {
      "name": "xxx",
      "pattern": "xxx"
  }
 ]
}
```

How are you trying to map the json into the object? 
Is it a request body for an api? Can you please provide that info.

Comment: this is request body of api and i am interested in single table.